# VS2012 Static Code Analyzer gives a false positive while de-allocating vector of memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, code-analysis

Consider the following Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <tchar.h>
bool foo()
{
    std::vector<TCHAR *> arr;
    TCHAR *szTableName = (TCHAR *)malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * 10);
    if (!szTableName)
        return false;
    arr.push_back(szTableName);
    memset(arr.back(), 0, sizeof(TCHAR) * 10);
    std::vector<TCHAR*>::const_iterator it = arr.begin();
    for (; it != arr.end(); it++)
        free(*it); // C6001 : Using uninitialized memory '*it.*()'.
    arr.clear();
    return true;
}
```

When I compile the above code with the compiler option `/analyze:WX-`, visual studio emits a warning

```
warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*it.*()'.: Lines: ....
```

for the line `free(*it);`.

Strange enough, you do not see the error if you allocate and insert multiple memory inside a loop. for example the following code does not cause VS2012 to emit any error

```
#include <vector>
#include <tchar.h>
bool foo()
{
    std::vector<TCHAR *> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        TCHAR *szTableName = (TCHAR *)malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * 10);
        if (!szTableName)
            return false;
        arr.push_back(szTableName);
        memset(arr.back(), 0, sizeof(TCHAR) * 10);
    }
    std::vector<TCHAR*>::const_iterator it = arr.begin();
    for (; it != arr.end(); it++)
        free(*it);
    arr.clear();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: False static analyzer warnings are a fact of life.  There is no advantage to C-style memory management, use new[] and delete[] instead and the warning disappears.

Comment: @HansPassant: `There is no advantage to C-style memory management, use new[] and delete[] instead and the warning disappears`, yes unless you are doomed with a legacy code :-)

Comment: There is no point in running a static analyzer on code that you can't or don't want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Static Analyzer is probably getting confused because of `operator*` overload in `iterator`. I have tried following, and it doesn't give warning:

```
auto x = *it;
free(x);
```

And:

```
free((void*)*it);
```

Interestingly, the loop, if it runs only once (`<1` condition), the warning is rendered. 
It is definitely a false-positive, and you have two options: either (a) ignore the warning, or (b) fool/appease the static analyzer somehow.